# Nodejs function to check if website is working

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm trying to make a function that checks if the given URL is working or not.
This is what I've done so far:

```
function checkWebsite(url) {
  http
    .get(url, function(res) {
      console.log(url, res.statusCode);
      return res.statusCode === 200;
    })
    .on("error", function(e) {
      return false;
    });
}
```

I want to wait until http get is finished and then return true or false based on the status code and being the response in a callback function I don't know how to return it back to where it was called.
Example call:

```
function test() {
   if (checkWebsite("https://stackoverflow.com/")) {
    return "https://stackoverflow.com/";
   } 
}
```

I want to get the true or false in this if statement but since the status code is in a callback function I don't know how to return it.

Comment: I've tried that but I wasn't able to make it work. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: No answer here will add any information to the answers in the related discussion. Take your time and read them, all the information you need is there.

Comment: Re read it and still no help... I need to return the status code but it is in a callback function

Comment: You can't wait and then return without using a spinlock, which is a very bad idea , since you have no reason to ever wait and then return in JavaScript. Like the linked answers explain, hust use the callback or use a Promise .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you a working snippet since you cannot figure it out from the linked answer, maybe it'll help you more:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

test();

function checkWebsite(url, callback) {
  https
    .get(url, function(res) {
      console.log(url, res.statusCode);
      return callback(res.statusCode === 200);
    })
    .on("error", function(e) {
      return callback(false);
    });
}

function test(){
    checkWebsite("https://stackoverflow.com/", function(check){
        console.log(check); //true
    })
}
```

With promises:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

test();

function checkWebsite(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https
        .get(url, function(res) {
          console.log(url, res.statusCode);
          resolve(res.statusCode === 200);
        })
        .on("error", function(e) {
          resolve(false);
        });     
    })
}
async function test(){
    var check = await checkWebsite("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    console.log(check); //true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked I could figure out how to use promises, even though I know how they work